# Android App - Play YouTube video on website, using WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

First of all, my problem:

I'm trying to "port" a mobile website to an application. This website has embedded YouTube videos, and these should of course be able to play in the actual application. My issuse is, they wont.
I can start the app, and the video will play fine, but if I try to make it fullscreen, the video pauses, and if I resume it again, it's only the sound playing. This also happens if I just pause the video and resumes. Only sound.

I've spent the last couple of nights googling like a mad man, but I've not found a working solution to my problem.

Targeting android API level 14.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    });



    mWebview .loadUrl("http://mobile.mmm.dk");
    setContentView(mWebview );
    this.mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone have any ideas what so ever feel free to shoot at it. I'm willing to try anything, even starting from scratch and implement the youtube API.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are gaining by simply putting a `WebView` in an app. That will never beat out a browser. To truly port your website, you should download any relevant data you need from your website (preferably through a service) and display it with native `View`s, true MVC.

Comment: It's a mobile version of a website, and it would just be so you had an App for it, instead of finding it trough your browser (I know you can just add it to favorites and save it on your homescreen).

Comment: Unless your app is taking advantage of device specific features that a web site cannot use, I and many other users resent apps that are just web containers, since they rarely ever perform better than using a browser with the site. Also, when users realize they are clicking links, it just doesn't feel native. It's really better to just have a mobile version of your website and optimize it for various devices and browsers if you aren't going to use any native controls.